# AJAX nesting content on call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have my website, http://www.yokaproject.com/, i decided to clean it up, im still in the process so if you see that i have mistakes fine, im not done, but i appreciate any comments. The nav at the top displays anchor tags to click and load jquery into the div#container. My problem is that calls are being doubled each time and nesting more and more content, just click art twice in a row. Ive been at this since last Monday so any help is appreciated. Here is my function

```
$('.header a').on('click', ajaxLoad);

function ajaxLoad(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var that = $(this);
    that.off('click'); // remove handler
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: "html",
      type: "GET",
      cache: false
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#container").html(data);
    });
};
```

If you want a better look at the html and css you can just visit my site. i plan on putting it up on github in the future once it gets larger but for now its not necessary.

- you can now view complete code on my website

Comment: in `always` function, you are again calling the ajaxLoad function in callback!

Comment: yup that fixed it

Comment: What fixed it? my suggestion or the first answer ?

Comment: both, i literally just had to remove that piece of code and it worked, thank you

Comment: I wrote this as an answer. Please accept it with an UP vote. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i unaccepted the answer @HimanshuUpadhyay, problem still persisting when you navigate from art tab to any other tab then back to art tab

Comment: Checking your website now.

Comment: it probably wont show updated code, godaddy hosting isnt that fast

Answer (score 0):

```
that.on('click', ajaxLoad); // add handler back after ajax
```

This line of code re-attaches the click handler every time an ajax response comes. And every time you click `that` you create an ajax request.

Comment: yeah ill accept this answer once the 7 min period is over, thanks for the answer

Comment: i had to unaccept this answer, problem still persisting when you navigate from art tab to any other tab then back to art tab

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is:
in `always` function, you are again calling the ajaxLoad function in callback! So it is calling multiple times. Please remove that line from you code.

Comment: you can now view my website, its completely up to date with the code above